# How to protect MySQL login Credentials in Native java app

Tags: java, mysql, security

I have a problem but I don't how to search & what to search for the solution. I am sure there will be some solution but I am not able search correctly so please help me solve the problem or either point me right direction.

**Presently**
I have written a Java Application which uses MySQL database to store data which is remotely located. Now that to run my application I have configured MySQL to access remote connections and my Java Application has properties file which stores MySQL credentials to login to MySQL server to perform queries.

**Problem**
 1. I am sure it is not the safe way to store MySQL credentials In Java Client apps.

2.While communication Java App will send MySQL credentials to login to server which is also not safe because it can be viewed by some one monitoring the network.

I know that it not the right approach to accomplish this solution. So what is the correct approach?

If similar question have been resolved earlier please direct me to the right source.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361659/encrypt-database-username-and-password-in-java

Comment: why not give unique username/pwd to each user and use that? mysql supports more than one user...

Answer (score 1):

1. Type the password on a login screen
2. Connect with a secure connection. Perhaps SSL / TLS ought to be considered

Comment: I don't want the application user to know the MySQL credentials. Secondly Will SSL/TLS prevent the network monitors from reading the credentials during communication.

Comment: I guess we can rule out an RSA Key Fob then too, since we are going really low budget and unsafe here